# How can I specify the server where an egg is?

Tags: python, buildout, pypi

In buildout I can enumerate eggs by name:

```
eggs =
  aa.ee
  ee.ii
  ii.oo
  oo.uu
```

By default, all that eggs are retrieved from https://pypi.python.org. How can I specify that the egg `ii.oo` must be retrieved from another package repository? For example I want ot specify that an specific egg is in `http://example` that runs using [pypiserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible indicate where to retrieve the egg from including the full path to it in the `find-lings` parameter. The following example is taken from [the pip docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html):

```
eggs = PILwoTk
find-links = http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/PILwoTk-1.1.6.4.tar.gz
```